# alternative at-symbol for cmbright

Tags: fonts, latin-modern, computer-modern

Is there a more "classical" at(@)-symbol that matches the cmbright-font as the symbol that's already included in the font? I already had a look at the [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://www.math.boun.edu.tr/instructors/gurel/symbols-a4.pdf) but it seems that there isn't any at-symbol that matches the cmbright-font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\emaila}{{\href{mailto:john.dole@abc.de}{john.dole@abc.de}}}
\newcommand{\emailb}{{\href{mailto:john.dole@abc.de}{john.dole\MVAt abc.de}}}
\begin{document}
\emaila
\emailb
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image: shows cmbright with the at-symbol in different fonts]

Comment: Related: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the standard computer modern at sign:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cmbright}

\newcommand{\myat}{{\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont @}}

\newcommand{\emaila}{{\href{mailto:john.dole@abc.de}{john.dole@abc.de}}}
\newcommand{\emailb}{{\href{mailto:john.dole@abc.de}{john.dole\myat abc.de}}}

\begin{document}

\emaila

\emailb

\end{document}
```

The same idea will allow you to pick the at sign from many other fonts.  Here is the result of

```
\newcommand{\myat}{{\fontfamily{pag}\selectfont @}}
```

chosen by the poster:

[image: Second sample]

Comment: Well, to be honest I don't like the at symbol in cm or lm either.

Comment: Thanks, I guess `\newcommand{\myat}{{\fontfamily{pag}\fontsize{11}{1}\selectfont@}}` will do the job. UPDATE: Just changed the fontsize of the at-symbol, otherwise the at-symbol seems to be a bit taller as cmbright at 12pt